# KML 2.2 parsing with a group of point Geotools

Tags: kml, java, geotools

I am doing a viewer with geotools and I am trying to read a kml file. I am using PullParser class for parsing and also I am using KML and KMLConfiguration classes from org.geotools.kml.v22 package. If I use a kml file with just one geometry, the code works, but when I try with a file with more than one point, it read only the first coordinates, even though it capture all the names of the points.
I don't know how to make possible to read more than one point of the same file
Do you know how can I solve this?

Here is the code:

```
void readKML(File file){
 fis = new FileInputStream(file);
 PullParser parser = new PullParser(new KMLConfiguration(), fis, KML.Placemark);
 int index = 0;
 DefaultGeographicCRS crs = DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84;
 SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder typeBuilder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
 typeBuilder.setName(file.getName());
 typeBuilder.setCRS(crs);
 typeBuilder.add("name", String.class);
 typeBuilder.add("the_geom", Geometry.class);
 SimpleFeatureType type = typeBuilder.buildFeatureType();
 SimpleFeatureBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(type);
 DefaultFeatureCollection newCollection = new DefaultFeatureCollection();
 StyleMap.GeomType geom = null;
 SimpleFeature f = null;
 while ((f = ((SimpleFeature) parser.parse())) != null) {
   String geometryDesc = f.getDefaultGeometry().toString();
   //This function is for making the style 
   geom = getGeometryType(geometryDesc);
   Geometry geometry = (Geometry) f.getDefaultGeometry();
   Object nameAttribute = null;
   nameAttribute = f.getAttribute("name");
   builder.addAll(new Object[]{nameAttribute, geometry});
   SimpleFeature feature = builder.buildFeature(String.valueOf(index++));
   newCollection.add(feature);
  }
}
```

I based on this reference:
[How to parse KML data using geotools?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4549/how-to-parse-kml-data-using-geotools)
and also on this code:
http://direct.massapi.com/source/github/17/47/1747678994/plugins/org.locationtech.udig.catalog.kml/src/main/java/org/locationtech/udig/catalog/kml/core/KmlUtils.java.html#85

Comment: can you add a link to your KML file?

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried the following with the [KML Samples file](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/KML_Samples.kml) Google provide and all works fine:

```
private ArrayList<SimpleFeature> features;

  public ParseKML(String path) throws XMLStreamException, IOException, SAXException {
    source = new File(path);
    InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(source);
    PullParser parser = new PullParser(new KMLConfiguration(), fis, KML.Placemark);
    SimpleFeature f = null;
    features = new ArrayList<SimpleFeature>();
    while ((f = (SimpleFeature) parser.parse()) != null) {

      features.add(f);
    }
  }

  private SimpleFeatureCollection getFeatures() {
    return DataUtilities.collection(features);
  }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you help @iant. I actually, try your and my code with the file you provides and it works fine. But it doesn't work with this file I created on Google earth [sample_file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4HXP1xhRqRaRkc1dHpiakFURWs/view?usp=sharing). I also tried with others files I also create with Google Earth and the results are the same.

Comment: your sample file gives me POINT (6.203382129855367 -75.56383925335378)
punto3
POINT (6.203382129855367 -75.56383925335378)
punto2
POINT (6.203382129855367 -75.56383925335378)
punto1

Comment: That's true. It is the same coordinates all the time, but the points are not the same. If I open the fine on Google Earth or using sublime or notepad. The coordinates are different for each point. Then, I don't know how to fix it. I also try creating a different file of points and it doesn't work.

Comment: Oops I hadn't noticed that. I'll have another look.